# Dynamic Dropdown from database in add template Grocery Crud

Tags: codeigniter-3, grocery-crud

I am having two relations first one category/second one product and the roduct relation contains the foreign key from the category relation. in my add template of product I wan to have a dynamic dropdown to select form categories. Right now I'm using this way.

```
 $crud->field_type('cat_id','dropdown', array('1' => 'Boxes', '2' => 'Supliments'));
```

but its is creating a static dropdown. As if any new category is added it doesn't reflect change over here and if i don't specify this I get a simple input field where I have to specify category myself. Right now I am using bootstrap theme. Is there any way I can create a dynamic dropdown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a set_relation() function in the grocery crud documentation that may solve your challenge.You can view the information via this link http://www.grocerycrud.com/examples/set_a_relation